# EditorConfig rule to disallow public C# fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, editorconfig

I'd like to add a rule which triggers for public instance fields in a class, to suggest using a property instead. I've seen some examples of rules which use a `required_prefix` to add a custom message.

What I currently have works to an extent. I get the following warning in Visual Studio:

> Naming rule violation: Missing prefix: 'Fields should not be public. Should this be a property?'

But it is a **warning**, and I'm expecting a **suggestion**. I do have a default severity set at above the custom rule, but I assume the specified severity in the rule should take priority?

Any ideas why VS is not displaying it as a suggestion? Is there a better way to achieve this? Thanks

```
#snipped

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = warning

#snipped

dotnet_naming_style.disallowed_public_field_style.capitalization  = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.disallowed_public_field_style.required_prefix = Fields should not be public. Should this be a property?

dotnet_naming_symbols.other_public_fields_group.applicable_accessibilities = public
dotnet_naming_symbols.other_public_fields_group.applicable_kinds           = field
dotnet_naming_rule.other_public_fields_disallowed_rule.symbols             = other_public_fields_group
dotnet_naming_rule.other_public_fields_disallowed_rule.style               = disallowed_public_field_style
dotnet_naming_rule.other_public_fields_disallowed_rule.severity            = suggestion
```

Comment: I think you also have to specify that the specific analyzer for that rule needs to become a suggestion. Now you only configure the code style rule, not analyzer rule. I could be wrong about this, but the ms docs about code style might prove me right/wrong. I can not currently point you in a better direction; apologies and good luck!

Comment: I think that the rule severity should take priority over the analyzer severity. See [Precedence section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options)